# Cannot add element with the same key to resource dictionary - it already exists

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

while parsing one xaml file I get an exception:

> Result Message:
>   Test method ThemeResourceDictionaryTest.ParseXaml threw exception: 
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Add value to dictionary of type 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary' threw an exception.' Line number '1397' and line position '4'. ---> System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox'  Key being added: 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox'

and my element:

```
<Style x:Key="MyVeryUniqueKey" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="90"/>
</Style>
```

Why is the key of the element set to TextBox, when I explicitly set the key to be MyVeryUniqueKey, which is unique.

I have other styles whose target type is TextBox, but they all have different keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that, in a particular resource dictionary scope, you have more than one `TextBox` style where the `TargetType` is set but the `x:Key` is not.

If you don't explicitly set the dictionary key for a `TextBox` style it will default to `{x:Type TextBox}`. You obviously can't have two of these duplicated as keys in a dictionary.

For example, if you put this kind of thing in resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Then you will get a runtime `XamlParseException`:

> Item has already been added.
>   Key in dictionary: 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox'
>   Key being added: 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox'"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with two styles with different keys.

x:Key has to be IN FRONT OF TargetType. I still can't believe it ...

Works:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"> ...
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"> ...
```

Doesn't work:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ButtonStyle"> ...
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ButtonStyle2"> ...
```

Comment: Not sure who's downvoting you, but this solved it for me. I cannot believe it either. Very strange that the attributes would be positionally dependent here, but sure enough, I moved `x:Key` ahead of `TargetType` and I stopped getting the error.